# Can I mix three wires that carry single phase 240V AC and four wires that carry USB signals into a signal custom cable?

Tags: signal-integrity, ac-dc, interference, wire-terminals

I am planning to design a system that requires AC power supply as well as a USB connection.  I found a connector that has provision for the same [here.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003782099533.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.11f8d5c1W1bUup&algo_pvid=0d836817-f652-46c8-a32a-74a7380e7670&algo_exp_id=0d836817-f652-46c8-a32a-74a7380e7670-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000027149224149%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B51.42%3B-1%3B1410%40salePrice%3BAED%3Bsearch-mainSearch)

If I were to pass 240 VAC single phase along with 4 cables that carry USB data signals, will the 240VAC introduce interference to the digital signals over a distance of 2meters?

Comment: USB uses controlled impedance lines to send GHz signals. That connector won't be the right impedance so it will generate reflections. For USB 1 speed that is probably ok. For USB2 you might get it to work if your USB device is close to the connector. You will need controlled impedance cable on the other end of that connector too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood of interference is very, very low - as evidenced by the fact that you can wrap USB cables all around and over AC power cords with no effect on the USB whatsoever. Just as long as the wires in the cable have appropriately rated insulation for the voltage you're using you should have no issues running AC mains and USB in the same cable.
The problem you're much more likely to face is that the data pins in that connector are wholly unsuitable for carrying USB signaling.
At best you might get away with an old, slow USB 1.x low-speed HID device, but anything more than that needs you to treat the entire USB link as an impedance-matched transmission line, and I doubt that even the manufacturer of that connector knows what its characteristic impedance is.
For much the same reason you also can't run USB over just any 4 wires. The D+ & D- data lines need to be a twisted pair with the correct characteristic impedance.